# Oracle MAF : Supports for Web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I know that, **Oracle MAF** is used to develop hybrid mobile application for both `Android and IOS device` with native look and feel.

I have created `REST Web Service` and deployed on the `WebLogic` server as described in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_persistance/tut_jdev_maf_persistance.html) and also created mobile client app for Android device with use of `Android SDK`. It is running successfully on `Android Device`.

Now, It is possible to run mobile client on server (May be `WebLogic, Glassfish, Tomcat`) so that it can be accessed as a  `Web Version` (**Web Application**).

---

As a try, I have zipped mobile client application as a `war` file and also deployed on `Tomcat` and `WebLogic` but without success.

Below is the error message which I got when accessing the home `URL` from `WebLogic` server.

```
Error 403--Forbidden

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.4 403 Forbidden

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.
```

Share yours ideas to resolve this issue if you have any, it will help current and future MAF developers.

Answer (score 2):

MAF creates application that deploy and run on the device.
ADF creates server side applications that can be accessed from the browser on a mobile device. 
Two separate architectures addressing two separate needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, We also got update from oracle official and they are saying that we can deploy MAF application into any server by doing some configuration. But they does't expose the way how to do. Please confirm by oracle document link which supports this answer, so that we can proceed further development. **P.S:** They (Oracle people) are marketing people's.

Comment: 'Your' Oracle official has made an mistake then. (Note that Shay is an Oracle PM for their mobile 'stuff')

Comment: Thanks @User404, now we can raise our voice on this question towards Oracle official.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. Zipping the `.apk` (Android) or `.ipa` (iOS) file will not make it a web application. Those files are also containers but they contain native code.

Use `Oracle ADF` for web applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, FYI i have zipped the project into **WAR** only. If MAF supports only for Mobile application why oracle proposed this new technology when ADF was there? And ADF supports for both mobile and web application(meaning same code base for both)?

Comment: Because ADF is an server side, web technology while MAF delivers native mobile applications (client side).

Comment: Fine., what about **ADF Mobile**? It is supposed to be Mobile technology right?

Comment: ADF Mobile has been rebranded to MAF and yes, it's a mobile technology.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.! :) so I assume, we need to have 2 individual code base for 'Mobile App' and 'Web Application'.

Comment: Yes. You can however expose some data from your web application (ADF) so that it can be used in your mobile application (MAF). But the code bases are indeed separated.